# Is it possible to create TODOs or Comments while in Debug mode

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I would like to flag a line of code for changing while I'm in debug mode, and associate some thoughts with it.  I've tried adding comments, but the debugger thinks that I'm trying to change code, and won't continue until I rebuild.  Something like Word's comment system would work too.

I know I could work around this if I turned on edit and continue, but there are good reasons why edit and continue is not turned on, and it's not really needed for what I'm asking.

I'm guessing there must be an extension out there that meets this need.

Update: If I try to add comments while edit and continue is turned off, I get a message that says, "This source file has changed. It no longer matches the version of the file used to build the application being debugged".  I had given up when I saw that message, but it turns out I can just say ok and move on.

Comment: This is a mysterious question.  Editing code while debugging with E+C turned off works just fine.  Continuing debugging after the edit is not a problem.  Document the language and the Tools + Debugging + General settings.

Comment: This exact problem led to me installing a sticky notes program in WinXP...  Adding just a comment to a line, at the end, without changing the line-count would force me to rebuild.  This was in ~2008.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually built into Visual Studio 2012 - no need for an extension. With your cursor on the offending line of code, go to Edit > Bookmarks > Add Task List Shortcut. Within the task list, a new entry with a copy of the line of code will be added (you may need to select 'Shortcuts' in the drop down first). You can then edit the content of that task item to contain your thoughts on what needs fixing.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to flag a line and don't need to add text, you can use the bookmark feature in Visual Studio: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2wffxsy0.aspx

This lets you flag multiple lines and then quickly navigate between them.

Comment: That is an interesting idea, it definitely gets me one step closer, and is a good fallback option.  The piece that I'm more interested in is associating my thoughts with the line, I really want some text.

Answer (score 1):

I use conditional breakpoints to store comments. Put your text in quotes and then your breakpoint window will show your thoughts.

Right click on your breakpoint and select Condition...

[image: conditional breakpoint]

Enter your notes:

[image: comments]

Then in the breakpoint window (Debug/Windows/Breakpoints) you can see everything you need to address:

[image: breakpoints with comments]

Answer (score 1):

To add to @David's answer, when adding a bookmark, you can name your bookmarks. For the name, I enter a short phrase about what I want to do with that bookmark, such as how I want to modify the code after debugging.
It helps to be viewing the bookmark window (View/Other Windows/Bookmark Window Ctrl-K, Ctrl-W). (I'm using VS 2015)

Answer (score 0):

A potential shim is "Pin to Source" for expressions which allows for comments and persists across debug sessions. I'm not entirely sure if one is able to edit them out of debug, but if you can live with that for simply commenting during debug, this might work

To pin an expression, highlight it, right click and choose "Pin to Source". Alternatively, you can hover over an in-scope variable until its pop-up appears. Click on the pin in the pop-up to pin it to your editing surface.

The chevron drop-down enables the comment text box.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **add comments to your codes** or even modify your codes while debugging your application.

But, remember: you should **Enable and Disable Edit and Continue**([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-enable-and-disable-edit-and-continue)) and check you are in **break mode**(rather than debug mode).